# Why is the index of my ArrayList index always returning -1?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a composition percent calculator (mainly to do my Chemistry assignments faster), and I am at the point where the actual calculations are being done. I am trying to get the masses from the elements the user puts in, but it always returns -1 and with this error:

[image]

I have tried to debug it, but my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) won't let me see the variables or try to check anything.

***NOTE:*** The error happens on line 64.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList ;
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit ;

import static java.lang.System.in ;
import static java.lang.System.out ;

public class Main {

    static void clearScreen() {
        out.println("\033[H\033[2J") ;
        out.flush() ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String elementID ;
        int totalElements ;
        int elementCount ;
        double elementMass ;
        double totalMass ;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in) ;
        ArrayList<String> elementNames = new ArrayList<>() ;
        ArrayList<String> wantedElements = new ArrayList<>() ;
        ArrayList<Integer> wantedElementsCount = new ArrayList<>() ;
        ArrayList<Double> elementMasses = new ArrayList<>() ;

        while (true) {
            out.print("\nEnter amount of elements in compound: ") ; totalElements = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) ;
            out.println("TOTAL ELEMENTS COUNT: " + totalElements + "\n") ;
            wantedElements.clear() ;
            wantedElementsCount.clear() ;
            
            for (int elms = 1 ; elms <= totalElements ; elms++) {
                out.print("Enter name for element #" + elms + " (it will be remembered if spelt correctly): ") ; elementID = sc.nextLine() ;
                out.println("ENTERED ELEMENT NAME: " + elementID + "\n") ;
                
                if (!(elementNames.contains(elementID))) {
                    elementNames.add(elementID) ;
                    out.print("Enter mass for element #" + elms + ": ") ; elementMass = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine()) ;
                    out.println("ENTERED ELEMENT MASS: " + elementMass + "\n") ;

                    if (!(elementMasses.contains(elementMass))) {
                        elementMasses.add(elementMass) ;
                    }
                    
                    wantedElements.add(elementID) ;
                } else {
                    wantedElements.add(elementNames.get(elementNames.indexOf(elementID))) ;
                }

                out.print("Enter the amount of the element there is: ") ; elementCount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) ;
                out.println("ENTERED ELEMENT AMOUNT: " + elementCount + "\n") ;
                wantedElementsCount.add(elementCount) ;
            }

            totalMass = 0 ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < elementMasses.size() ; i++) {
                totalMass += elementMasses.get(i) ;
            }

            for (int i = 0 ; i < wantedElements.size() ; i++) {
                out.print("% MASS OF " + wantedElements.get(i) + ": ") ; 

            // The wantedElements.indexOf() part tries to get the index of the current elements that the user wants to use in the given equation, which will correlate with the elementMasses list

            out.println(elementMasses.get(wantedElements.indexOf(i)) * wantedElementsCount.indexOf(i) / totalMass * 100) ;  // This is where the error happens
            }

            out.println("TOTAL COMPOUND MASS" + totalMass) ;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [mre].

Comment: "but my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) won't let me see the variables or try to check anything" I very much doubt that.

Comment: It just says "Variables debug info no available"

Comment: `wantedElements.indexOf(i)` is *searching* for `i` in the list, is that correct? Not really consistent with printing `wantedElements.get(i)` (line before). Anyway, always check the result of `indexOf()`: `-1` indicates that nothing was found

Comment: Can you explain in detail what your code is supposed to do? `wantedElements.indexOf(i)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Sweeper - damn, you were 15 seconds faster. Yea, thats the spot :)

Comment: Also logically `totalMass += elementMasses.get(i);` does not make sense because you are only counting each mass a single time, but it sounds like you have multiple occurences of each element, so you would need to multiply the element mass by the number of elements then add it to get the total mass. 
This is throwing off your answer even if you do fix your error.

Comment: also note that `elementNames.get(elementNames.indexOf(elementID))` is basically retsulting in `elementID` (or an error if `elementID` is not in the list) -- it basically does: search the index of `elementID`, return the value at that index, which *must* be `elementID`

Comment: Also `!(elementMasses.contains(elementMass))` checks to see if two elements have the same mass and then won't add it, so if a user types `6` for two different element's masses, your code will crash with an out of bounds error later.

Comment: By the way, text should be as text, not as an image.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your line:

```
out.println(elementMasses.get(wantedElements.indexOf(i)) * wantedElementsCount.indexOf(i) / totalMass * 100)
```

This part:

```
elementMasses.get(wantedElements.indexOf(i))
```

doesn't make sense which is why it's throwing an error.

When using indexOf, you should be passing a wantedElement in there, not integer "i". For example:

If you have a list of wantedElements with 2 values in that list, say "Test1" and "Test2". Then performing wantedElements.indexOf("Test1") would return you an index of 0 and wantedElements.indexOf("Test2") would return you an index of 1.

As I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do in your example, it's hard to assist any further. Hopefully this gives you a better understanding of how the indexOf() function works to aid you going forward with your project